# tornado multi process crash with nltk

Tags: python, crash, tornado

I'm getting some very strange behaviour in a tornado application. 
I'm running a lot of processes each which have their own HTTP servers and running on a different port.

I added a new process to the system which is another TCPServer class that listens on an entirely different port and doesn't have any interaction with the other processes.

I bring the new server up as follows:

```
def runSimService(port):
   sim=SimService()
   sim.listen(port)
   currentIOLoop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
   currentIOLoop.start()

class SimService(TCPServer):
   def __init__(self,host='localhost',motorport=27017):

      TCPServer.__init__(self)
      self.log=logging.getLogger("tornado.access")

      # Needs to contain a User class log. 
      self.con=motor.MotorClient(host,motorport)
      self.db=self.con.pDB
      self.col=self.db.pCol
```

Basically that's the only code I left when debugging. The crash i get isn't a normal python exception crash which is worrying me.

[image]

I'm developing on a mac the moment. Can someone please explain is this crash is something wrong with my code or is there something else happening here?'

### UPDATE:

Ok this is really bizare it only seems to happen when I import the following:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
```

OR

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
```

or nltk in general...

Could there be some weird interaction between libraries happening? I'm stuck

### Code to create processes

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
   AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient",max_clients=2000)

   processes=[]

   processes.append(Process(target=runSimServer,args=(...,)))
   processes.append(Process(target=runServer,args=(...)))
   processes.append(Process(target=runServer,args=(...)))
   processes.append(Process(target=runServer,args=(...)))
   processes.append(Process(target=runServer,args=(...)))
   processes.append(Process(target=runServer,args=(...)))

   # write pids to pid/ directory for use with the shutdown program
   with open("pid/"+__file__.split(".")[0]+".pid","w") as f:
      for p in processes:
         p.start()
         f.write(str(p.pid)+"\n")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of that crash message is "multi-threaded process forked". If you are going to use both threads and processes, you must fork all your processes before creating any threads. It looks like `nltk` is creating some threads when you import it. If you are also using multiple processes (it doesn't look like you are from the code you quoted, but that is obviously incomplete), you must not import `nltk` until after all processes have been started.

Comment: Hi Ben I have added how I create all the processes. The runServer function starts the HTTP application server. These also have some other TCP servers for IPC. The runSimServer is independent however this was the process that was importing the nltk and causing the crash. So are you saying that I need to start all the other processes before importing the nltk within the simServer? Aren't the threads within the simServer independent? Why would they affect the other processes?

Comment: Please post a *complete*, *runnable* example including all imports. Importing `nltk` from within `runSimServer` (and therefore within a child process that doesn't fork again) should be fine, but that doesn't appear to be what you're doing based on the `runSimService` method quoted above.

Comment: Thanks Ben, whilst interested to know what is happening I have actually moved from nltk to spacy for language processing and the problem stopped. Unfortunately posting a complete runnable example would be difficult anyhow. Actually I made a mistake the runSimServer in the process creation should be runSimService.. Either way it's working for now. Thanks for pointing out that i needed to create all my processes before creating any threads. This is good to know for the future. Cheers